# Python separating Ajax requests from normal page views

Tags: python, ajax, django, design-patterns, xmlhttprequest

I'm wondering what are some strategies that you've come up when dealing with this. I'm new to the python/django framework and would like to separate the serving of view from the handling of ajax requests (xhr).

I'm thinking of having a separate file xhrHandler.py and route specific POST/GET requests to /xhr/methodname and then delegate the views.py methods to return the view passing along the httprequest for view processing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `request.is_ajax()` and delegate wherever you need. Sample handler:

```
def view_something(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       # ajax
    else
       # not
```

You can now call different functions (in different files) for the two cases.

If you want to be fancier, use a decorator for the handler that will dispatch ajaxy requests elsewhere:

```
def reroute_ajaxy(ajax_handler):
    def wrap(f):
        def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[0].is_ajax():
                return ajax_handler(args)
            else:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorate
    return wrap

def score_ajax_handler(request):
    print "score ajax handler"


@reroute_ajaxy(score_ajax_handler)
def score_handler(request):
    print "score handler"
```

And some mock testing to exercise it:

```
class ReqMock:
    def __init__(self, ajax=False):
        self.ajax = ajax
    def is_ajax(self):
        return self.ajax


score_handler(ReqMock(True))
score_handler(ReqMock(False))
```

Produces:

```
score ajax handler
score handler
```

Comment: Hmm, I think i should reword my question. I know how to handle the requests, was just wondering what are some strategies in separating ajax handling with view handling. ie. not having to handle ajax requests in views.py

Comment: i proposed handling it in separate files rather than in the view, right way about it? or is there a better way?

Comment: @Floetic: the decorator approach I proposed doesn't even require you to acknowledge the existence of ajax in the normal request handler - it's rerouted by the wrapping function, and you can reroute it to a different file. It takes you 1 extra line (the decorator call) to support AJAX for that request - doesn't look like a big burden on `views.py`!